# UV unwrapping however black background appears

Tags: uv, transparency, color

I was wonder if anyone can help me. I am trying to unwrap a texture however whenever I unwrap it, it shows a black background. I want to save it as a png file with a transparent background but because there's this black background it shows it up in the png file.

[image]

Comment: You want to save the UV layout or the texture?

Comment: so, basically I want to export the design as a obj.file but before I do that I need to unwrap my textures but whenever I do that it creates this black background and it needs to be transparent. I've tried it on a different layer and it works fine.